# C# GUI in Linux/OSX

Tags: c#, linux, winforms, macos, user-interface

So far I've been doing C# development with `emacs` + `csharp-mode` + `mcs` and it's been successfully emulating an IDE. Now I have to develop some Windows Forms application. Is there a tool for Linux like the simple GUI builder in VS? What about OS X?

Comment: Have you looked at [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)? GTK# applications run on Windows, OS X and Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mono Develop http://monodevelop.com/ has support for building WinForms on Unix based systems.